# Disable tooltipText in BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, material-components

Im using

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'
```

this is my menu

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/llHome"
    android:icon="@drawable/selector_menu_home"
    android:title="@string/navigation.bottom.home"
    app:tooltipText="@null" />
```

but as much as I write long click or disable it, the tooltip with the name of the menu continues to appear. Any idea how to disable the tooltip?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will either show the tooltip text or the tab title. You might be able to clear out the text by iterating over all the `BottomNavigationItemView`s and calling `TooltipCompat.setTooltipText(view, null)`

Comment: This works! I call the following code inside my Fragment.onViewCreated()
```bottomNavigationView.menu.forEach {
            TooltipCompat.setTooltipText(activity!!.findViewById(it.itemId), null)
}```

Comment: Is there a XML solution?

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE you can add a binding adapter using data-binding

Answer (score 5):

This not works for me, `bottomNavigationView.menu.forEach {             TooltipCompat.setTooltipText(activity!!.findViewById(it.itemId), null) }`is not working so below answer worked for me

```
bottomNavigationView.menu.forEach {
                val view = bottomNavigationView.findViewById<View>(it.itemId)
                view.setOnLongClickListener {
                    true
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually

```
bottomNavigationView.menu.forEach {
    TooltipCompat.setTooltipText(activity!!.findViewById(it.itemId), null) 
}
```

is not working after pressing the bottom button.

Here is my solution:

```
fun BottomNavigationView.disableTooltipText() {
  try {
    val menuViewField = this.javaClass.getDeclaredField("menuView")
    menuViewField.isAccessible = true
    val menuView = menuViewField.get(this) as BottomNavigationMenuView
    menuView.forEach {
      it.setOnLongClickListener {
        true
      }
    }
  } catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.w(e)
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't like the idea of using reflection to do these things, but setting the long click listener part works for me.

Answer (score 1):

We could create an extension with this answser:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58240404/9871226

```kotlin
fun BottomNavigationView.disableTooltipText() {
    val menuIterator = menu.iterator()
    while(menuIterator.hasNext()) {
        val menu = menuIterator.next()
        findViewById<View>(menu.itemId)?.let { view ->
            TooltipCompat.setTooltipText(view, null)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing was working for me until I combined the above answers and did this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bottomNavigationView.getMenu().size(); i++) {
        bottomNavigationView.findViewById(bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).getItemId()).setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
```